# Wired connection and ad-hoc wireless at the same time

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, server, adhoc

I'm setting up an Ubuntu Server 14.04 with a wired connection (p4p1) and creating an ad-hoc wireless network. Here's my interfaces file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp

# WiFi
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-mode ad-hoc
wireless-channel 4
wireless-essid Augmented Learning
wireless-key 1234567890
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.2
```

Things are running smooth when one of the two interface is up, but when both are up, I can neither access Internet (via p4p1) nor access my ad-hoc network (with wlan0).

What should I do to run them both at the same time ? I don't need to share the connection.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I have sufficient knowledge to answer, but I believe more experienced users would like to see the output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should not do is point the gateway to your own IP. The gateway tells the system how to route to any IP address *not* in any of the subnets to which it is directly connected. Normally this is the route to "the Internet", so should not be present for a connection to an internal network unless the route to the Internet is on a host on that network. So remove the `gateway` line from your definition of `wlan0`.

There may be multiple things wrong here, so this might not be the only change needed to fix your problem.

Comment: Commenting the gateway line worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe i know how you could use a file called asleep.d it can be downloaded here.

https://app.box.com/s/5nj2xuhby5kqk1y3o7wb

you just copy it over to /etc/pm

Comment: Why would I put the network manager to sleep ? Could you explain a bit more what does this script does and why?

Comment: it could maybe work this way that it's unsleep the network by making it false.